# Graphical, user friendly representation for 'All', 'Some', 'None'

Tags: user-interface, user-interaction, interaction-design

I'm building a reporting tool where the user can filter results by selecting one or more options from various checkbox lists.

To save space I'd like to shrink each list once the selections are made but have a symbol next to each to remind the user whether they have picked some, all or none of the options.

I could use the words 'filtered' and 'none' but was trying to think if there was a simple icon which would convey the same thing.

Has anyone tackled this before or seen a good example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the filter icon and fill it with different levels to indicate the options.

For example:

[image: Filter Levels]

Excuse my dodgy sketches - but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

If i understand you question properly then this is what you are after